# Non-interactively setting an icon for an .exe after/while compiling with cl.exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, icons

Is there an *automated* way to embed an .ico file into an .exe during or after compilation? I only have the command line tools `cl.exe`, `link.exe` etc. available, i.e. I do **not** want to add an icon in the Visual Studio interface by add it via a project config setting but have this as a separate step in a build system (which generates icons from png-files during the build process).

Comment: Create an `.rc` file with an `ICON` resource in it referencing the icon file on disk and link the .res output into your executable. The `.rc` files are just text so you can automate the creation with a script if you want.

Comment: @AndyBrown, what do you do next?  If I am doing cl /EHcs hello.cpp, how do I use the .rc file with this to put the icon in the exe?

Comment: @VinceWest call `rc.exe ABC.rc` which results in an `ABC.res` file (see `rc /?` for more options). Then add this file to the other `.lib` and `.obj` arguments for `link.exe`.